# add new field to the result of a mongo aggregation

Tags: spring, mongodb, aggregation-framework

when i try to add new field with a specific value it's working fine on mongo shell :

```
db.getCollection('collName').aggregate([
{ "$group" : { "_id" : "$idcpt" , "sum" : { "$sum" : "$val"}}},
{$addFields : {idcpt : 1092}}
])
```

But when i try to implement this aggregation in spring using org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation

i have difficulties with the "addFields", i can't find the right combination :

```
 Aggregation.match(criteria),
 Aggregation.group("idcpt").sum("val").as("sum"),
 Aggregation.fields(....)
```

any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$addFields` is not part of the spring data support library yet, https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation.supported-aggregation-operations.

I faced the same issue earlier, and I ended up just running it as raw query.

```
 BasicDBList doc = (BasicDBList) JSON.parse(aggregateQuery.toString()); //where aggregateQuery is a StringBuilder that prepares the query string.
 List<DBObject> pipeline = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Object aDoc : doc) {
        DBObject stage = (DBObject) aDoc;
        pipeline.add(stage);
    }
    AggregationOutput output =  mongoTemplate.getDb().getCollection("collName").aggregate(pipeline);
```

Comment: thanks for replying :)
Casting from dbobject to basicDBList seems not to be working, i had a castexception when running my code.

Comment: In the snippet that I posted, there is no such casting.. and it is working code. There might be some other issue in the way you prepare the query string maybe.

Comment: i have tested the query generated and it's a valid json.
the JSON.parse returns a DBObject. So when i try to get the variable doc, a casting exception occured

Comment: actually JSON.parse returns an Object, which I cast to BasicDBList. Could you check if your import is `com.mongodb.util.JSON` ? http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/util/JSON.html#parse-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 1):

This might be late but `$addFields` is now supported in spring-data support library.

[Official Docs Link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/AddFieldsOperation.html)

You can create it like this:

```
Aggregation.addFields()
            .addFieldWithValue("idcpt", 1092))
            .build()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I found in the link provided by @Bajal that you can make a project AND add new fields at the same time with 'andExpression'

```
Aggregation.project("_id", ...).andExpression("1092").as("idcpt");
```

this is the idea but it doesn't work.
To make it work you need to change slightly the expression :

```
Aggregation.project("_id", ...).andExpression("0 + [0]", 1092).as("idcpt");
```

I guess andExpression needs an expression to calculate, but I didn't cheked more closely.

see for exemple : https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation.examples.example5

Answer (score 0):

Based on spring docs and I found we could use Aggregation as below.

> Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
>      Aggregation.project("test",...).andExpression("[0]",1092).as("idcpt "));

and like this.

> Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
>      Aggregation.project("test",...).and(1092).asLiteral().as("idcpt "));

Hopes to help you.